# How to give a default value to the local file in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I would like to give a default value to my component Avatar from React Native Elements because I have not prepared all the icons files required. However, when I use the OR logic, it fails to work. What is the proper way to do that?

```
          {sites.map((key) => {
            return (
              <Avatar
                size={32}
                containerStyle={{ margin: 0, padding: "0.1em" }}
                rounded
                source={
                  require("../../assets/" + utils.getPathName(key.properties.nameEN, "icon.png")) ||
                  require("../../assets/default/icon.png")
                }
                onPress={() => {
                  displayModal(key);
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```js
var IMG;
try {
    IMG = require("../../assets/" + utils.getPathName(key.properties.nameEN, "icon.png"));
} catch (e) {
    IMG = require("../../assets/default/icon.png");
}

{
  sites.map((key) => {
    return ( 
    <Avatar 
    // other props...
      source = {IMG}
    />);
  })
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. `require("../../assets/hk/" + utils.getPathName(key.properties.nameEN, "icon.png"))` still gives a value that is neither null nor undefined even if it doesn't exist. But thank you for your advice still!

Comment: Still getting the error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './lionrock/icon.png'`

Comment: What about this? Just edited my answer

Comment: The idea works now. Yet I have to modify a bit because I am generating a list of avatars dynamically. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your icons will change through time, you'll have to use state.

Also, you may want to use `Image` instead of `Avatar` to better handle `onError` events.

```js
const icon = require("../../assets/" + utils.getPathName(key.properties.nameEN, "icon.png");
const temp_icon = require("../../assets/default/icon.png");

const MyAvatar = ({ source, size }) => {
  const [avatarSource, setAvatarSource] = useState(source || temp_icon);

  const handleImageError = () => {
    setAvatarSource(temp_icon);
  };

  return (
    <Avatar
      size={32}
      containerStyle={{ margin: 0, padding: "0.1em" }}
      rounded
      renderAvatar={() => (
        <Image
            source={avatarSource}
            onError={handleImageError}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
);
```